# React query how to handle a search

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I'm just playing around with react query

I'm building sort of a simple github clone

I have to use useQuery twice one for the current user

as router param the other with a new search.

I ended up with:

```
const history = useHistory();
  const currentUser: string = useRouterPathname();
  const [user, setUser] = useState(currentUser);
  const handleFormSubmit = (data: SearchFormInputs) => {
    history.push(`/${data.search}`);
    setUser(data.search);
  };
  const { isLoading, error, data } = useGetUserData(user);
  if (isLoading) return <p>Loading...</p>;

  if (error) return <p>An error has occurred: " + {error}</p>;
  console.log(user, data);
```

Is it the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important part is probably that in `useGetUserData`, you put the `user` *into* the queryKey of react-query, something like:

```
const useGetUserData = (user) => useQuery(['users', user], () => fetchUserData(user))
```

so that you always refetch data when the user changes and users are not sharing a cache entry between them.

Something not react-query related though: The good thing about react-router is that you can also use it as a state manager - their hooks also subscribe you to changes, so there is no real need to duplicate that with local state:

```
const history = useHistory();
const currentUser: string = useRouterPathname();
const handleFormSubmit = (data: SearchFormInputs) => {
  history.push(`/${data.search}`);
};
const { isLoading, error, data } = useGetUserData(currentUser);
```

once you push to the history, all subscribers (via `useParams` or `useLocation`) will also re-render, thus giving you a new `currentUser`.

Lastly, I would recommend checking for data availability first rather than for loading/error:

```
const { error, data } = useGetUserData(user);
if (data) return renderTheData
if (error) return <p>An error has occurred: " + {error}</p>;
return <p>Loading...</p>
```

it obviously depends on your use-case, but generally, if a background refetch happens, and it errors, we still have `data` (albeit stale data) that we can show to the user instead. It's mostly unexpected if you see data on the screen, refocus your browser tab (react-query will try to update the data in the background then per default), and then the data disappears and the error is shown. It might be relevant in some cases, but most people are not aware that you can have `data` *and*  `error` at the same time, and you have to prioritise for one or the other.